# WebMvcTest with Spring Security seems to incorrectly return 404 - possible bug? or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

When testing a controller with WebMvcTest and Spring Security (using Boot 3 and Security 6), the authorization seems to be failing. Testing the endpoint with no user returns a 401 as expected, but when a valid user is provided, it returns 404, not 200.

Note that I have read through many different blogs and samples and the Spring Security documentation, in particular this section https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html - of course there is a lot of information available but some is for older versions of Spring Security, or older versions of JUnit, or for Spring MVC, not Spring Boot... and so on, so it is quite difficult to figure out what is the right way to acutally write the tests, so please forgive me if I have done it incorrectly. I went with the information from what seems to be the most authorative source - the docs linked above.

### To Reproduce

This repository contains a small application that reproduces the issue. This was created from Sprng Initializr. Just clone the repo and run "mvn test".
Notice that the test fails and reports a HTTP 404.
For comparison, comment out the @WithMockUser annotation on the test method, and run it again. This time you will get a 401, which is expected.
https://github.com/markxnelson/spring-security-webmvctest-reproducer

I have also tried adding the @EnableMethodSecurity annotation, but the behavior did not change.

### Expected behavior

I expect that the test as written should pass, i.e., it should authenticate as that user and have the necessary role to call the hello method, and therefore recieve back a response with HTTP 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for adding a reproducer for your issuer. Combining Spring Security's `MockMvc` support with Spring Boot's `@WebMvcTest` is tricky because it requires exactly the right annotations (combining the wrong ones seems to break the tests).

I'm not clear on why you include your security configuration outside of production code, but regardless you can simply use `@WebMvcTest` (boot) and `@Import` as in the following example:

```java
@WebMvcTest(DemoController.class)
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
class DemoApplicationTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext) {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user")
    void shouldSayHello() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/hello"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I also changed the `WebApplicationContext` to use method injection.

This example is not currently in the docs that I'm aware of, since we haven't typically had Spring Boot specific documentation. It could be a good addition though. We're always looking for contributors, so feel free to open an issue and suggest changes to improve the docs!

Comment: Thanks Steve, that does indeed work.  You're right it is tricky to get the right combination.  I went through many combinations, I guess I just missed that one.

The SecurityConfig is outside the production code only to simplify the reproducer, in my real code I hve another (different) one in the production code.